# Limiting the number of entries in a list control MFC

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I need to limit the entries that appear in my list control since two much entries make my MFC program slow. Is there a way to show only the last few entries (say for an example the most recent 100 entries) in a list control???

Thank You!!!

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in "showing" these items? Theoretically showing strings in a list box adds no performance penalty - could be that your problem lies not in showing these entries but in creating/storing them.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at virtual list control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye4z8x58%28VS.80%29.aspx

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/advanced/article.php/c4151

Answer (score 0):

Either you:

- don't add too many items (clear contents, only add the 100 you want in it)
- use virtual list mode like Alex says.